# Trying to grab into edit mode (curve path) but it does weirdly?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, path

I'm trying to grab vertices in edit mode (it is a curve path) in order to do hair. Last time I used Blender it was grabbing good, but today when I'm grabbing it, the results are pretty weird. It wasn't doing this the last time I tried to make the hair so I don't understand what happened. Do you have any idea of why it is grabbing like that (maybe I click by mistake somewhere and I can't remember) ? And how to resolve it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might help if you add a screenshot of your object data properties. (In case you don't know, it's the button near the bottom right of the screen that consists of two green squares connected by a line.)